# Erro java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

estou começando a aprender java e no meu código simples de entrada de argumentos no programa está dando o erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Este é o meu código:

```
public class Saudacao {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Saudacao, " + args[0]);       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de exercício, geralmente, é realizado através da linha de comando(cmd, powershell, bash, etc).

Na linha de comando, após compilar a classe você faria como exemplo:

```java
java Saudacao Gianluca
```

E o resultado na linha de comando seria:

```java
Saudacao, Gianluca
```

Em tempo de execução a máquina virtual procura pelo conteúdo no primeiro índice do Array args.
Como você não passou nenhum argumento a máquina virtual cria um Array de tamanho 0.
 Como não existe elementos, não existe índice 0 e quando tenta acesssar lança uma Exception.

Comment: Certo, fui no terminal na minha maquina virtual e deu tudo certinho, muito obrigado.
Mas... como faço no VScode? direto no windows, sabe me dizer?

Comment: Parte superior: Terminal ~> Novo Terminal. Na parte inferior abrirá o terminal. (:

Comment: Show, ajudou muito, abs